# Why spatially overlapping clusters?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I would like to know why sometimes overlapping clusters exists in a clustering analysis? For example, the picture below shows the result of HCPC from Factominer. It is strange and I can not find a reason for that. If that is related to the clustering algorithm, then is that a sign of bad clustering algorithm?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have other dimensions as well, so the overlap in 2d may not be that alarming, considering the two dimensions account for less than half of the variance.

Comment: This appears to be a plot of clustering in more than two dimensions.  The clusters likely do *not* overlap.

Comment: Yes. There are other dimensions too. Do you mean that in an n-dimensional space, clusters don't have overlap?

Comment: Think of your plot as a bunch of shadows of the clusters, like the shadows of tree leaves on the ground at noon: the leaves don't overlap but their shadows do.